# Redirect Request to parent directory using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server-administration

Suppose the user request for the content such as image in `www.example.com/content/img/one.jpg.`

If the **one.jpg** is in the directory img then the image is served. But if the **one.jpg** is not present then user is redirected one directory up to `www.example.com/content/one.jpg`.

Whether it has the requested file or not.

It must be valid for all content such as images or documents or videos 
etc.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ______________________
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?/)?[^/]+/(.+)$ $1$2 [L]
```

Comment: Actually i want it for all request.. only the last one directory should be redirected to its parent directory if there is not content. I think we are close.

Like http://52.74.73.123/img/two.png also need to show the content 

which is in http://52.74.73.123/two.png

Comment: But this is not working 
http://52.74.73.123/img/another/one.gif

http://52.74.73.123/img/one.gif [Image is here should have shown]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74501/discussion-between-ganesh-pandey-and-anubhava).